# How to deploy Neo4j snapshot build to a custom Maven repository?

Tags: maven, neo4j, repository

When I try to build neo4j from sources and deploy it, the deployment phase fails since there is already a repository defined in the `grandparent`'s `pom.xml`. 
Is it possible to redefine (or add) the `DistributionManagement` properties so that I'll be able to deploy custom neo4j build to an internal non-local repository?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible since maven-deploy-plugin 2.8

Just be sure to use that version of the plugin (by defining it in neo4j's pom if neo4j doesn't already do that by itself)

Then define `altReleaseDeploymentRepository`and/or `altSnapshotDeploymentRepository` in your maven settings.xml. (Depending on your personal preference you can also define that inside a profile).

The syntax of the alternative repositories is `id::layout::url` where id must match the id of a server that is also defined in your settings (giving you the chance to give user/pass for that server). Layout is `default`
Example:

```
<altReleaseDeploymentRepository>my.nexus::default::https://my.domain.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases/</altReleaseDeploymentRepository>
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I'm impressed by how you've guessed what I wanted even though I posted a totally different question :)